# How to squash a merged commit with other commits

Tags: git

I am facing difficulties in squashing a merged commit, what could be the best way of implementing this, for example below is the screenshot of the 3 commits, I can only manage to squash the 2 (This one  `4241338` and this `5b820c3`) but I can't squash the merged commit (`bcee6c9`) with the other 2, my goal is to have only one commit on my PR, how best can I do this :

[image]

**NOTE:**

My blocker is on the merged commit

Comment: You cannot squash a merge commit. The whole idea makes no sense. What's the real goal here?

Comment: I want to have only one commit on my PR, and the fact that I can't squash it, it's counted on my PR why ?

Comment: But you are the one who started by merging `prod`. What was the purpose of that?

Comment: This was due to the update of prod and my branch, I used a merge approach not rebase

Comment: Then you shouldn't have done the merge. You have hit yourself in the face and now you are complaining that someone is hitting your face. At this point your best bet is to shut down this PR and start over on a new branch without the merge. You can cherry pick the good commits onto the new branch so there will be no new work to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen into [the X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/237313). Your actual requirement is this:

> I want to have only one commit on my PR

You've identified "squashing" as a possible way to achieve this, but run into problems because you needed to merge in other people's work.

A more appropriate solution is a **rebase**: replay your changes as though they had all happened *after* everybody else's work. That way no merge will be needed, and you will be free to combine your changes into one.

In short, you would run:

```
git rebase -i prod
```

Then in the "todo list" that pops up, change "apply" to "squash" for all except the first commit.

Search online for "git rebase" to find out more; there's no point me repeating all the details here when they're already covered many times elsewhere.